# Is there any harm using hyperref for a document destined for printing?

Tags: hyperref, printing

I am using the `hyperref` package in my LaTeX document, and then using `pdflatex` to generate the pdf file.

Is there any harm in print quality, in using the `hyperref` package?

Or should I have two versions of my document, one for viewing on the screen (with `hyperref`) and one for printing (without `hyperref`)?

This is how I have set up the package.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,
            bookmarksnumbered,
            citecolor=black,
            urlcolor=black,
            linkcolor=black
            ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % Correct a problem with hyperref, don't know 
                         % what problem it is supposed to correct :)
\hypersetup{
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My Title},    % title
    pdfauthor={My Name},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject of Document},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={My Name},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={My Name}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={Test} {Document}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have any harm. Colorlinks can be other than black so that you have colored links in pdf. To make them black only  while printing, please use `ocgcolorlinks` instead of `colorlinks`.

Comment: The main possibly negative impact is colorlinks (and other use of colour) if you are printing in monochrome this greys out all link text, and generally coloured links may be distracting in a format like paper where they are not active (but you can turn off colour for print versions without removing hyperref)

Comment: To add to the isssues already mentioned, you have to remember that the URL's are gone in printing. E.g., I set up my bibliography style so that URL's are links on the title of references, because it looks much nicer, and noone will type those URL's by hand anyway. In a print version, I consider printing the URL's visibly.

Comment: A remark: use the option `hypcap=true` of package `caption` instead of the outdated package `hypcap`.

Comment: The ocgcolorlinks option is marked experimental in the manual for hyperref, and at least on Linux (via CUPS) it prints in color (really grayish on B&W printer).

Comment: some third party pdf viewer tend to not behave properly with pdf documents that have thing for display and different things to printing. the most common example is the box around links: adobe reader will not print them while it will display then on screen, however packages such as linux viewer of the type of okular will print them. I suspect it is due to the underlying pango library not supporting these elements yet, but it is an issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone comments. I have decided not to use ocgcolorlinks since it does seem buggy (and I do use Linux). But have taken Kurt's advice and removed hypcap.

Comment: @ArTourter: not printing these boxes seems the right thing to do. So isn't it rather a bug of okular type viewers to print them? ah... sorry I think this is what you meant too.

Comment: Since you are using LaTeX, I think is a safe assumption that you want the best quality result. For printed matter I don't see the value of having boxes around references which are links. Plus someone like me might try to click in the TOC and get annoyed that book did not automatically flip open to the correct page :-)... (to be continued...)

Comment: ...continued from above:  Since it is fairly easy to generate two versions of the documents (at least several orders of magnitude less than required to produce the document in the first place), you should spend the little bit of extra time ensuring that the printed document is of the best possible quality as well as the online version by providing two different versions.

Comment: A clarification regarding my comments on 3rd party pdf viewers. my experience may have been slightly out dated as it seems recent versions of okular at least respect the pdf specifications in that regard. This may still be an issue with some packages, but it seems that the faulty behaviour has started to disappear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no harm in using hyperref for a document that will go to printing.  To illustrate its flexibility should an issue occur, you could use any of the following options:

`colorlinks` - Gives color to your links or boxes off your links with colored borders

`hidelinks` - Hide all of your links, removing all the colors and borders

`linkcolor` - Set the color of all your links

`citecolor` - Set the color of all your citations

`filecolor` - Set the color of all your file links

`urlcolor` - Set the color of all your URL links

Given in RGB specification:

`linkbordercolor` - Set the color of your border around links

`citebordercolor` - Set the color of your citation borders

`urlbordercolor` - Set the color of your URL borders

In summary, the only foreseeable issue with hyperref and printing may be the colors it may impose on your document.  Switching from color to grayscale is as simple as modifying a global setting in your document beforehand.  There is no need to compile without hyperref when you can compile with hyperref on color and hyperref on black.

[More information](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization)